# Read Firefox 3 bookmarks

Tags: java, sqlite, parsing, firefox-3, bookmarks

Firefox 3 stores the bookmarks in a sqlite database.
There are several hacked sqlite java libraries available.
Is there a way to hack the sqlite database in java(not using libraries) to read bookmarks reliably?
Does someone know how the sqlite DB is stored and access programmatically (from java)?

Answer (score 5):

You need the [SQLite JDBC driver](http://www.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/) (this page explains how to run queries on a SQLite database using that driver from within Java).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you need NOT to use a JDBC driver, but there's another possible "solution" depending on your software requirements. In FF3, type in the address bar about:config

Alter the value of property: browser.bookmarks.autoExportHTML to true.

This will export your bookmarks in an HTML whenever you close FF. You can then read the HTML. It may or may not solve your problem....

Comment: Although is definitely a good alternative.  You only get what Firefox exports.  If you connect to the database, you can get everything you like.